# Where should I setup the markup of header/footer? In \fancyxxx or in redefinition of \xxxmark?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, best-practices, fancyhdr

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\sf\color{black}\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\tt\color{black}\leftmark}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\tt\color{black}\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\sf\color{black}\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the first variant. The second variant will, possibly among other things, not account for your header changes in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% GOOD
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
% \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
% \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\sffamily\rightmark}
% \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\ttfamily\leftmark}
% BAD
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\ttfamily\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\sffamily\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

EDIT: Replaced LaTeX 2.09 commands `\sf` and `\tt` with `\sffamily` resp. `\ttfamily`.