# How to define a header/footer style using \fancypagestyle?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

## Question

How to define a header/footer style using `\fancypagestyle` ?

## Minimal Code (does not work)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{ttt}
{%

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\tt\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\sf\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
}

\pagestyle{ttt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` *after* choosing `\pagestyle{ttt}`. Also, did you read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9120/where-should-i-setup-the-markup-of-header-footerin-fancyxxx-or-in-redefin/9122#9122) answer?

EDIT: Sorry for being snippy - you may have read my other answer before I edited it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already read your prev post. Good!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that inside `\fancypagestyle{foo}{<stuff>}`, redefining macros that take numbered arguments need to have their `#`s "escaped" like this:

```
\fancypagestyle{ttt}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\tt\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ ##1}{}}%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\sf\thesection\ ##1}}%
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}%
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}}
```